# Outlook Exchange Active Sync with roaming profiles

Tags: roaming-profile, activesync, outlook-2016

I have some computers with Win 10, Outlook 2016 and roaming profiles.
I want to access email through **Exchange ActiveSync**

When I configure Outlook, the OST File ist stored in %userprofile%\appdata\local\Microsoft\Outlook

So far, so good. However, Outlook saves the path in the registry with  C:\users\username\appdata\local\Microsoft\Outlook without using the variable

This causes a problem if the user profile is stored under C:\users\username.domain on another computer. This can happen if the "username" folder already exists.

What I‘ve found/tried so far:

- Setting KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\ForeOSTPath
  as explained in 
  https://support.microsoft.com/de-at/help/2752583/you-cannot-change-the-location-of-the-offline-outlook-data-file-ost-in 
  This did not work. Even after creating a new Outlook profile.
- Disabling the „Cached Mode“ is not available. I think this Option is only available with „Microsoft Exchange“ but not with „Exchange ActiveSync“ (whatever the difference is)
- Setting a sybolic link, as mentioned on some websites, doesn't seem to be a good solution, since under certain circumstances windows create user profile folders with a suffix.

Comment: Is Active-Sync actually working? (Certificates are installed, etc...)

Comment: Yes everything is working unless the user use a different computer where the user profile is in an other directory

Comment: Here’s a similar case for your reference. https://forum.kopano.io/topic/99/outlook-with-roaming-profile-on-different-computers